# What is the most efficient way to get every combination of values from 3 collections?

Tags: clojure, iteration

As the title suggests, I am trying to get every combination of values from 3 collections (and then make a keyword containing one of each value). The best way I could come up with is:

(the `coord-seq` function generates a collection that I would like generate values)

```clj
(map
  (fn [x] (map
    (fn [y x] (map
      (fn [z y x] (keyword (str x "," y "," z " ")))
      (coord-seq game last radius)
      (repeat y)
      (repeat x)))
    (coord-seq game second radius)
    (repeat x)))
  (coord-seq game first radius)))
```

Something I was not able to do, however, in this example, was to add all generated keywords to a collection.

Is there an efficient way to do all of this?

Comment: TL;DR: If you have exactly 3 collections, just use a list comprehension: `(for [x (coord-seq game first radius),
      y (coord-seq game second radius),
      z (coord-seq game last radius)]
  [x y z])`.

Comment: Yep @Carcigenicate, that's pretty much exactly what I am looking for, thanks!